# ansible, execute a task only if another specific host is also in the playbook run

Tags: ansible

I have a little problem I can't solve. I am writing an update/reboot playbook for my Linux servers and I want to make sure that a task is executed only if another host is in the same playbook run

for example:

- stop app on app server when the database server is going to be rebooted

```
- hosts: project-live-app01
  tasks:
    - name: stop app before rebooting db servers
      systemd:
        name: app
        state: stopped
      when: <<< project-live-db01 is in this ansible run >>>

- hosts: dbservers
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: Unconditionally reboot the machine with all defaults
      reboot:
        post_reboot_delay: 20
        msg: "Reboot initiated by Ansible"

- hosts: important_servers:!dbservers
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: Unconditionally reboot the machine with all defaults
      reboot:
        post_reboot_delay: 20
        msg: "Reboot initiated by Ansible"
```

I want to use the same playbook to reboot hosts and If i --limit the execution to only some hosts and especially not the dbserver then I don't want to have the app stopped. I try to create a generic playbook for all my projects, which only executes tasks if certain servers are affected by the playbook run.

Is there any way for that?

thank you and have a great day!
cheers, Ringo

Comment: Your idea is not feasible. The first play (hosts: project-live-app01) does not know what hosts (hosts: dbservers) will be managed by the next plays.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to create a dictionary with the structure of the project, e.g. in *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all
project_live:
  app01:
    dbs: [db01, db09]
  app02:
    dbs: [db02, db09]
  app03:
    dbs: [db03, db09]
```

Put all groups of the DB servers you want to use into the inventory, e.g.

```
shell> cat hosts
[dbserversA]
db01
db02

[dbserversB]
db02
db03

[dbserversC]
db09
```

Then the playbook below demonstrates the scenario

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
---
- name: Stop app before rebooting db servers
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Stop app on {{ item.key }}"
      loop: "{{ project_live|dict2items }}"
      when: item.value.dbs|intersect(groups[dbservers])|length > 0

- name: Reboot db servers
  hosts: "{{ dbservers }}"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Reboot {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

For example

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -e dbservers=dbserversA

PLAY [Stop app before rebooting db servers] ***********************

  msg: Stop app on app01
  msg: Stop app on app02

PLAY [Reboot db servers] *******************************************

  msg: Reboot db01
  msg: Reboot db02
```

How can I stop services on app* when the play is running on the localhost? Either use *delegate_to*, or create dynamic group by [*add_host*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html#ansible-builtin-add-host-add-a-host-and-alternatively-a-group-to-the-ansible-playbook-in-memory-inventory) and use it in the next play, e.g.

```yaml
shell cat playbook.yml
---
- name: Create group appX
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item.key }}"
        groups: appX
      loop: "{{ project_live|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
      when: item.value.dbs|intersect(groups[dbservers])|length > 0

- name: Stop app before rebooting db servers
  hosts: appX
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Stop app on {{ inventory_hostname }}"

- name: Reboot db servers
  hosts: "{{ dbservers }}"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Reboot {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -e dbservers=dbserversA

PLAY [Create group appX] ******************************************

ok: [localhost] => (item=app01)
ok: [localhost] => (item=app02)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=app03) 

PLAY [Stop app before rebooting db servers] ************************

  msg: Stop app on app01
  msg: Stop app on app02

PLAY [Reboot db servers] *******************************************

  msg: Reboot db01
  msg: Reboot db02
```

Comment: thank you! that was a lot of effort! cheers, Ringo